# Solr 7 - Phrasal Match with same prefix

Tags: solr, lucene, solr7

I want to retrieve results which match tokens (edgeNGramed). It works as expected for tokens which do not share prefixed. But for tokens which are sharing prefixes, Solr doesn't work as expected. Eg: if the indexed term is `bird box` and query is `bird b`, solr will return results which only has `bird` and maybe with tokens `bird box` following it (Since our index is huge, I haven't verified it yet)

**Query Construction**

```
titlePhrasalFielName:"bird b"~2
```

> **Solr Version - 7.7.1**

[Link to Analyzer Chain's Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApXVd.png)

Here is my analyzer chain.

```
    <fieldType name="payloadPhrasal" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_payload.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="30"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <similarity class="com.apple.its.uss.solrcomponents.PayloadSimilarity"/>
    </fieldType>
```

Any thoughts on how to make sure content with `bird box` gets recalled with `bird b` before any other content which only has `bird`.?

> Note

- Already seen stackoverflow question to index token in different field, we do not want to follow that approach and index can grow too huge and we token length can be literally anything.
- We just moved from Solr 4.10 to Solr 7.7.1, the behaviour is same in both versions. Haven't explored Solr 8 for this use case.
- Do not want to store all the prefixes (space squashed) in a multivalued field. eg: `b`, `bi`, `bir`, `bird`,`birdb`, `birdbo` & `birdbox` as this results in over recall for some very common use cases. Meaning it breaks more cases than it actually solves.

Comment: Try the ComplexPhraseQueryParser with `inOrder=true` as my initial guess is that the `~2` may be what's giving you the results that shouldn't be included. It'd be helpful with the output from `debug=all` as well to see why `bird` is recalled above `bird box`.

Comment: No luck, tried it. We need the `~2` to take care of synonyms (not added as part of solr analyzer but some other sources).